# The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect....... package did not load correctly...' after installing update 4 into VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I receive the following error message whenever I run VS2013 Premium after installing update 4. (Run as admin, Pc is at home office)

Is there a fix please?

What does SetSite do, that it complains about?

I don't use TeamArchitect so am I able to disable/uninstall it?

Note: I may have tried to uninstall premium then installed professional at some time (because my msdn subs is professional but msdn downloads offer premium as if I'm entitled to it) but that's an impossible task without reformatting as it keeps telling me I have premium whatever I do.

[image: screen shot]

Log file section of interest

```
  <record>818</record>
    <time>2015/01/09 09:10:46.299</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.DesignersCommon.DesignersCommonPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.DesignersCommonPackage, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{59E21B88-8E88-47DE-9FEE-935FA485AF40}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>819</record>
    <time>2015/01/09 09:10:46.304</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.DesignersCommon.DesignersCommonPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.DesignersCommonPackage, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{59E21B88-8E88-47DE-9FEE-935FA485AF40}</guid>
    <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>820</record>
    <time>2015/01/09 09:10:46.304</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.DesignersCommon.DesignersCommonPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.DesignersCommonPackage, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{59E21B88-8E88-47DE-9FEE-935FA485AF40}</guid>
    <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can start visual stutio with reset all setting:
Open command line

```
cd..
cd..
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio XX.0\Common7\IDE
(XX is 14 with visual studio 2015, XX is 12 with visual studio 2013)
devenv.exe /resetsettings
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
devenv /setup /ResetSkipPkgs
```